# Swift UIcollectionViewcell grid layout subView on device rotation not updating correctly (programmatically)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have a UICollectionView that has a number of custom UICollectionViewCell(s) setup as subviews.

I have laid out one of these custom cells in a grid (6 x 2).

[Portrait View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDCDm.png)

Upon rotation of the device (landscape), the grid view expands the correct frame width, however, the 6x2 layout is lost.

[Landscape View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paI4O.png)

I have setup the Home ViewController with...

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

The custom SubView has...

```
    import UIKit

    class ActivityCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

        private let cellId = "cell"

    // Month names
    let months: [String] = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()

        }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

        var gridLayout = Gridlayout(numberOfColumns: 6)
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.isScrollEnabled = false
        cv.collectionViewLayout = gridLayout
        return cv
    }()



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        let textLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.myAppWhite
        textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        textLabel.textAlignment = .center
        textLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.myAppWhite.cgColor
        textLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textLabel.text = months[indexPath.row]

        cell.contentView.addSubview(textLabel)

        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: textLabel)
        cell.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: textLabel)

        return cell
    }

    func setupViews() {

        self.addSubview(appsCollectionView)

        appsCollectionView.delegate = self
        appsCollectionView.dataSource = self

        appsCollectionView.register(AppCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: appsCollectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: appsCollectionView)
    }

    // Detetect if UICollectionViewCell was selected
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.myAppRed
        print("Selected: \(indexPath.row)" )
    }

    // Detetect if UICollectionViewCell was deselected
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        print("DeSelected: \(indexPath.row)" )
    }

}

    class AppCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

My custom GridLayout class looks like this...

```
import UIKit

class Gridlayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var numberOfColumns: Int = 6

init(numberOfColumns: Int) {
    super.init()
    self.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override var itemSize: CGSize {

    get {
        if let collectionView = collectionView {

                let columns = 6
                let margings = 2 * (columns - 1)

                let width = (collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(margings)) / CGFloat(columns)
                let height = width // square cells

                print ("Hello")


                return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }

        //Default
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    }

    set {
        super.itemSize = newValue


       }
    }

}
```

My UIView extension (View constraints)

```
extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

How do I resize my gridview so that the (6 x 2) layout stay the same (only larger to fit the screen)?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

      guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
      }

      if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
        //logic for the cell size if phone is in landscape
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100);
      } else {
        //logic if not landscape 
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50);
      }

      flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```